# Using WITH results in another query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to store the results of a query via `WITH`, and then use its results in another query like so:

```
WITH results AS (
    SELECT
        date,
        value
    FROM fruits
    WHERE fruit_name = 'apple'
    LIMIT 1
)
SELECT 
    date,
    quantity,
    CASE
        WHEN fruits.date < results.date THEN fruits.quantity * results.value
        ELSE 0
        END AS "valueColumn"
FROM fruits;
```

I'm trying to generate a new column called `valueColumn` in this query. But to do so I need to use information in `results`.

The query as written above gives me a `missing FROM-clause entry for table "results"` error. How can I use information in `results` as part of my query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`results` is like a table.  You have to include it in a `FROM` clause to use it.  In this case, it has one row, so `CROSS JOIN` suffices:

```
WITH results AS (
      SELECT date, value
      FROM fruits
      WHERE fruit_name = 'apple'
      LIMIT 1
     )
SELECT f.date, f.quantity,
       (CASE WHEN f.date < r.date THEN f.quantity * r.value
             ELSE 0
        END) AS "valueColumn"
FROM fruits f CROSS JOIN
     results r;
```

I assume that your question is specifically about CTEs.  There are simpler ways to express this query.  For instance, you can use window functions.  Assuming there is one row for `'apple'`:

```
SELECT f.date, f.quantity,
       (CASE WHEN f.date < MAX(f.date) FILTER (WHERE f.fruit_name = 'apple') OVER ()
             THEN f.quantity * MAX(f.value) FILTER (WHERE f.fruit_name = 'apple') OVER ()
             ELSE 0
        END) AS "valueColumn"
FROM fruits f
```